# How to deserialize from my JSON array to an array of dictionaries whose values are my "Resource" objects in C# .NET using Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm getting the following error when trying to deserliaze my JSON into a `Dictionary<string, Resources>[]`:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MyProject.Resource][]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

My Program.Main():

```
    public class Program
            {
                public static void Main(string[] Args)
                {
                    var options = new Options()
                    {
                        Option1 = "foo",
                        Option2 = "bar",
                        Resources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Resource>[]>(resources.json)
                    };
                }
            }
```

My resources.json:

```
{
    "global": [

        {
            "title": "global1",
            "url": "~/global1"
        },
        {
            "title": "global2",
            "url": "~/global2"
        }
    ],
    "ACC": [
        {
            "title": "acc1",
            "url": "~/acc1/"
        },
        {
            "title": "acc2",
            "url": "~/acc2/"
        }
    ],
    "ECC": [
        {
            "title": "ecc1",
            "url": "~/ecc1/"
        },
        {
            "title": "ecc2",
            "url": "~/ecc2/"
        }
    ],
    "ECB": [
        {
            "title": "ecb1",
            "url": "~/ecb1"
        }
    ]

}
```

My Resource class:

```
public class Resource
    {
        public List<string> titles { get; set; }

        public List<string> urls { get; set; }
    }
```

My Options class:

```
public class Options
    {
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Resource>[] Resources { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON does not represent an array of dictionaries (`Dictionary<string, Resource>[]`), it represents a dictionary of arrays (`Dictionary<string, Resource[]>`).  That is why you are getting the error.

Also, your Resource class needs to be defined like this to match the JSON:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

You can then deserialize like this:

```
 Resources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Resource[]>>(resources.json)
```

See fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8s2eQd

Answer (score 1):

Your Json doesn't match up with your class structure.
If you want to keep your class structure your json has to look like this:

```
{
   "global":{
      "titles":[
         "global1",
         "global2"
      ],
      "urls":[
         "~/global1",
         "~/global2"
      ]
   },
   "acc":{
      "titles":[
         "acc1",
         "acc2"
      ],
      "urls":[
         "~/acc1",
         "~/acc2"
      ]
   },

   ...    

}
```

If you can't influence your json file (for what ever reason) your class structure has to look like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
   public Global[] global { get; set; }
   public ACC[] ACC { get; set; }
   public ECC[] ECC { get; set; }
   public ECB[] ECB { get; set; }
}

public class Global
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ACC
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ECC
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ECB
{
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it like this:

```
Resources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(resources.json)
```

---

*Little note for the next time:*
If you are not sure how your class structure has to look like (regarding to a json string), you can copy the json string and go to:

> Visual Studio -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

and Visual Studio will make up the appropriate class structure.